# (Java) Can not fix array out of bounds error 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexoutofboundsexception

I keep getting this `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5` error and don't know why.  I'm trying to store in numbers into my 2D array from a text file but its not storing the data in correctly.  Also I am not allowed to use any predefined java methods such as the ".length" instance field as I store the data into the 2D array. Basically I have a class file that interacts with the driver file.

Here is the text file called "`numbers`":

> ```
> 3
> 5
> 8
> 2
> 4
> 1
> 7
> 9
> 11
> 14
> ```

Here is the class file which has the methods:

```
public class array_class2D//class header
{
 //private instance variables

  final private int rows = 4;
  final private int columns = 5;
  public final int maxsize = 20;

  int r = 0;
  int c = 0;
  private int position_r = 1;
  private int position_c = 2;

  int[][] c_array = new int[rows][columns];

  public void arrayPrint2D()
  {
   System.out.println("Printing out the Complete array: ");

   for(int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
   {
     for(int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
     {
        //if( count2 < count || c_array[r][c] != 0 )
        //{  
           System.out.print(c_array[r][c] + " ");
          // count2++;
        //}
     }

     System.out.println();
   }
  }


  public void store2D(int num)
  {
    System.out.println("R: " + r);
    System.out.println("C: " + c);
    c_array[r][c] = num;

    if(r == 0 && c < columns)
    {
     c++;

    }
    else if(r == 0 && c == columns)
    {
     r++;
     c = 0; 
    }
    else if(r == 1 && c < columns)
    {
     c++;
    }
    else if(r == 1 && c == columns)
    {
     r++;
     c = 0;  
    }
    else if(r == 2 && c < columns)
    {
     c++;
    }
    else if(r == 2 && c == columns)
    {
     r++;
     c = 0;
    }
    else if(r == 3 && c < columns)
    {
     c++; 
    }
    else if(r == 3 && c == columns)
    {
     r++;
     c = 0;
    }
    else if(r == 4 && c < columns)
    {
     c++;
    }
    else
    {
     System.out.println(" Its Done. ");
    }
  }      


}
```

And Here is my Driver File:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class array2D_Driver
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
  //Intance variables  
  int num = 0;//used to store elements from txt file
  int input;//used to store user input
  int number = 0;//used in while loop below to test user input



  //object to use methods 
  array_class2D object = new array_class2D();


  //Scanner object to read keyboard input
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  //Opens the file
  File file = new File("numbers.txt");
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);



  System.out.println("***************Array Manipulation Program****************");

  System.out.println("\n\n");

  //Calling print method to show arrat is empty
  object.arrayPrint2D();
  System.out.println();//Buffer line

  //Reads the file elements into the array
  while (inputFile.hasNext())
  {
     num = inputFile.nextInt();//Basically each line on the text file has one element that is stored into the 'num' variable.
     object.store2D(num);//The num variable is then passed as a integer through the store method's parameters
  }
  object.arrayPrint2D();

 }
}//End of main method
```

Thank-you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if-else` check in method `store2D()` is not necessary and too messy. Change it like this:

```
public void store2D(int num){
    System.out.println("R: " + r);
    System.out.println("C: " + c);
    c_array[r][c++] = num;
    if(c==5){
        c=0;
        r++;
    }
}
```

Thats it.

Comment: Welp that worked out! thanks Rafa! Its crazy how much shorter your code is but i understand what you were saying about all the unnecessary checks i made. Thanks a lot i post again if something else comes out.

Answer (score 0):

I  think Here is your problem

```
  c_array[r][c] = num;
```

When the loop reaches to the `columns` variable to `5` in  `public void store2D(int num)` this method is being called because there may  data more than the array dimensions , To avoid this try to give Array dimensions dynamically based on the data in That file.

Comment: oh i see what you mean.  But actually the 2d array is supposed to be partially filled as the text file only has 10 elements to input. Since i set the array to have 4 rows and 5 columns i thought it would have more than enough space. (thankyou for replying!)